# Is there a right way to manage different types of users in a database?

Tags: mysql, database

I have just set up a user registration for the first time. The users are stored in a MySQL database and everything works right now, but I know this isn't the best way to do this. The users can have different types of accesses, right now there are 5 different access types, but there might be many more in the future.

Currently, the users table is set up something like this (I'm skipping some columns):

```
id     |username    |password    |access1 |access2 |access3 |access4
----------------------------------------------------------------------
1      |user1       |12345678    |1       |0       |0       |1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
2      |user2       |12345679    |0       |0       |1       |0
```

So user1 has access to whatever is allowed for access levels 1 and 4 and user2 has only got access to 3.

In the future, there might be access10 or even more and there will be dozens of users.

I know this isn't really the right approach to do this, as I would have to keep adding access columns (and change some code as well) whenever I need to make minor changes.

I thought I might make it simple, by doing something like this:

```
id     |username    |password    |accesses 
-------------------------------------------
1      |user1       |12345678    |1,4       
------------------------------------------
2      |user2       |12345679    |3
```

but I also find that a bit hard to work with. E.g. when I select from the table using WHERE accesses LIKE '%2%' I could be getting access no. 12.

A third option would be to have a separate table that looks something like this:

```
user_id |access
-----------------
1       | 1 
-----------------
1       | 4 
-----------------
2       | 3
```

Right now, I am leaning towards this last method. But I feel like I might be overlooking something. As I am pretty new to coding and databases I hope you can assist me before I allow users to register so I can prevent problems down the line.

Is there a right way to do this?

Comment: You want to have a "roles" table or something similar, and then a table to relate users to "roles". There are MANY ways to go about even that one technique.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend going a step beyond your 3rd option. Have 3 tables: one for users, one for the various roles that can be held, and one that actually links users to their role(s).

Your *user* table would stay similar to how it is now, just without all the access_X columns.

Your *roles* table:

```
id | name
---------------
1  | User
---------------
2  | Admin
---------------
3  | Sales
---------------
4  | Inventory
```

And your *user_roles* table to link the two together:

```
id | user | role
-----------------
1  | 1    | 2
-----------------
2  | 2    | 1
-----------------
3  | 3    | 1
-----------------
4  | 3    | 3
-----------------
5  | 3    | 4
```

Comment: I had thought of something like that, as I remember some sites having that sort of thing. But the trouble is always that my roles are different. One role for me would be sales, another would be inventory, and yet another would be e-commerce. Some people would need to have access to two or more "roles".

Comment: Are you perhaps saying that the user_roles table could contain many rows for the same user?

Comment: Yes, a single user would appear once in the user_roles table for each role that they have. I'll update my example

Comment: Thanks, @Raptord tried this out a little bit and it just feels right :)